# tooltip view SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, tooltip, hint

I created tool tip in swiftui, but when I use it with overlay - frame is break.

```
import SwiftUI

struct HintBox: View {
    @State private var showTooltip = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Here text")
                    TooltipView(text: "it's hint! it's hint! it's hint! it's hint! it's hint! it's hint!", isVisible: $showTooltip)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            showTooltip.toggle()
                        }
        }
    }
}

struct TooltipView: View {
    var text: String
    @Binding var isVisible: Bool
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            if isVisible {
                Text(text)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                
                
                Triangle()
                    .fill(Color.gray)
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 10)
                    .offset(y: 0)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Triangle: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX - 10, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY - 10))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + 10, y: rect.minY))
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}
```

I need to make it so that I can determine exactly where the triangle will be (bottom or top), in the middle, or left or right. and also, it must be above other views. i.e. point with a triangle at the view to which I will attach it. and when you click on it, it should stop being displayed

Answer (score 3):

You might find that a [`popover`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/popover(ispresented:attachmentanchor:arrowedge:content:)) gives you the functionality you want, without having to re-invent it. However, on an iPhone, a popover is shown as a sheet.

Otherwise, one way to implement this is to show the hint as an overlay over the source view. An overlay automatically adopts the size of the underlying view and using a `GeometryReader` you can find the size of the source view in this way.

You want the hint to be able to break out of the bounds of the source footprint. This is done by using `.fixedSize()`. However, this means, the overlay is no longer centered, so you have to apply an offset to bring it back to center.

Then, to align the hint above, below, before or after the source view, you need to know the size of the hint itself. Here you can use the same technique again, setting an overlay over a hidden version of the hint and using another `GeometryReader` to find its size.

Here is an attempt to show it working:

*EDIT: Updated to take a closure as parameter. If the hint consists of long text then the caller can set a sensible width for it.*

```swift
struct HintBox: View {
    @State private var showTooltip = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Text here")
                .overlay {
                    TooltipView(
                        alignment: .top,
                        isVisible: $showTooltip
                    ) {
                        Text("it's hint! it's hint! it's hint! it's hint! it's hint! it's hint!")
                            .frame(width: 200)
                    }
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    showTooltip.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}

struct TooltipView<Content: View>: View {
    let alignment: Edge
    @Binding var isVisible: Bool
    let content: () -> Content
    let arrowOffset = CGFloat(8)

    private var oppositeAlignment: Alignment {
        let result: Alignment
        switch alignment {
        case .top: result = .bottom
        case .bottom: result = .top
        case .leading: result = .trailing
        case .trailing: result = .leading
        }
        return result
    }

    private var theHint: some View {
        content()
            .padding()
            .background(Color.gray)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .background(alignment: oppositeAlignment) {

                // The arrow is a square that is rotated by 45 degrees
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.gray)
                    .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(45))
                    .offset(x: alignment == .leading ? arrowOffset : 0)
                    .offset(x: alignment == .trailing ? -arrowOffset : 0)
                    .offset(y: alignment == .top ? arrowOffset : 0)
                    .offset(y: alignment == .bottom ? -arrowOffset : 0)
            }
            .padding()
            .fixedSize()
    }

    var body: some View {
        if isVisible {
            GeometryReader { proxy1 in

                // Use a hidden version of the hint to form the footprint
                theHint
                    .hidden()
                    .overlay {
                        GeometryReader { proxy2 in

                            // The visible version of the hint
                            theHint
                                .drawingGroup()
                                .shadow(radius: 4)

                                // Center the hint over the source view
                                .offset(
                                    x: -(proxy2.size.width / 2) + (proxy1.size.width / 2),
                                    y: -(proxy2.size.height / 2) + (proxy1.size.height / 2)
                                )
                                // Move the hint to the required edge
                                .offset(x: alignment == .leading ? (-proxy2.size.width / 2) - (proxy1.size.width / 2) : 0)
                                .offset(x: alignment == .trailing ? (proxy2.size.width / 2) + (proxy1.size.width / 2) : 0)
                                .offset(y: alignment == .top ? (-proxy2.size.height / 2) - (proxy1.size.height / 2) : 0)
                                .offset(y: alignment == .bottom ? (proxy2.size.height / 2) + (proxy1.size.height / 2) : 0)
                        }
                    }
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                isVisible.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: HintWithWrappedText]

Comment: cool! but if I have long text - it appear wrong.

Comment: Answer updated to take a closure as parameter. If the hint consists of long text then the caller can set a sensible width for it.

Comment: This is great! Im trying to adapt this View to use with my specific use case. I find that the hint layout doesnt seem to work fine unless I provide a hardcoded width frame on the View that is received as a parameter (the Text view in this example), is there any way to make it so it takes the entire width minus 20px horizontal padding? setting .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) + .padding(.horizontal, 20) doesnt seem to work :/. Thanks again.

Comment: @stompy The reason why `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` + padding is not working is because the hint is shown as an overlay, so the `.frame` modifier only makes it as wide as the view it is applied to. To have it use the full screen width - 20px, you could use a `GeometryReader` as the top-level container for the main `body` and measure the screen size that way. You can then use this to compute the width to apply to the hint content. If you are still having difficulties then I would suggest posting a new question. Ps, if the answer helped, you are welcome to vote it up ;)

Comment: That makes sense @BenzyNeez , thanks for the reply. Ive been trying to make the speech bubble / tooltip view take the entire width minus 20pts horizontal padding but I havent been able to get much progress, sadly. I went ahead and created a separate thread so I can maybe get some more specific help over there, would appreciate if you could take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77687680/swiftui-reusable-guided-tour-spotlight-effect-view-component

And of course I upvoted your solution since it was super helpful. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Benzy Neez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20386264/benzy-neez)'s answer is great, but it can be further improved.

First of all, we can combine the solution with [Mojtaba Hosseini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5623035/mojtaba-hosseini)'s technique of reading the size of a sibling view described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77358264/5623035). The resulting code is more neat and doesn't require multiple `GeometryReader`s or hidden copies of child views.

Secondly, the padding and background color can be a part of the API. Additionally, appearing/disappearing can be animated.

The implementation will looks like this:

```swift
private struct TooltipPopup<Content: View, Tooltip: View>: View {

  var body: some View {
    ChildSizeReader(size: $contentSize) {
      content
    }
      .overlay {
        hint
          .drawingGroup()
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
          .opacity(visible ? 1.0 : .zero)
          .animation(.default, value: visible)
          .shadow(radius: .halfPadding)
          .offset(x: (alignment == .leading) ? (-hintSize.width / 2.0) - (contentSize.width / 2.0) : .zero)
          .offset(x: (alignment == .trailing) ? (hintSize.width / 2.0) + (contentSize.width / 2.0) : .zero)
          .offset(y: (alignment == .top) ? (-hintSize.height / 2.0) - (contentSize.height / 2.0) : .zero)
          .offset(y: (alignment == .bottom) ? (hintSize.height / 2.0) + (contentSize.height / 2.0) : .zero)
        }
  }

  private let alignment: Edge
  private let backgroundColor: Color
  private let content: Content
  @ViewBuilder private let tooltip: () -> Tooltip
  @State private var contentSize = CGSize.zero
  private var hint: some View {
    ChildSizeReader(size: $hintSize) {
      tooltip()
        .background(backgroundColor)
        .cornerRadius(.defaultCornerRadius)
        .background(alignment: oppositeAlignment) {
          Rectangle() // The arrow is a square rotated by 45 degrees.
            .fill(backgroundColor)
            .frame(square: .fullPadding)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(45.0))
            .offset(x: (alignment == .leading) ? .halfPadding : .zero)
            .offset(x: (alignment == .trailing) ? -.halfPadding : .zero)
            .offset(y: (alignment == .top) ? .halfPadding : .zero)
            .offset(y: (alignment == .bottom) ? -.halfPadding : .zero)
        }
        .padding(.fullPadding)
    }
  }
  @State private var hintSize = CGSize.zero
  private var oppositeAlignment: Alignment {
    switch alignment {
      case .top:
        .bottom
      case .bottom:
        .top
      case .leading:
        .trailing
      case .trailing:
        .leading
    }
  }
  @Binding private var visible: Bool

  init(content: Content, alignment: Edge, visible: Binding<Bool>, backgroundColor: Color = .white, @ViewBuilder tooltip: @escaping () -> Tooltip) {
        self.content = content
        self.alignment = alignment
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        self.tooltip = tooltip

        _visible = visible
    }

}
```

Which implies you have `ChildSizeReader` defined and implemented as this:

```swift
struct ChildSizeReader<Content: View>: View {

  var body: some View {
    content()
      .background(GeometryReader {
        Color.clear.preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: $0.size)
      })
      .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { size = $0 }
  }

  private let content: () -> Content
  @Binding private var size: CGSize

  init(size: Binding<CGSize>, content: @escaping () -> Content) {
    self.content = content
    _size = size
  }

}

private struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
  static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
  static func reduce(value _: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) { }
```

Finally, we can turn the view into a view modifier:

```swift
extension View {
  func tooltip(alignment: Edge, visible: Binding<Bool>, backgroundColor: Color = .white, @ViewBuilder tooltip: @escaping () -> some View) -> some View {
    modifier(TooltipDisplayingModifier(alignment: alignment, visible: visible, backgroundColor: backgroundColor, tooltip: tooltip))
  }
}

private struct TooltipDisplayingModifier<Tooltip: View>: ViewModifier {

  private let alignment: Edge
  private let backgroundColor: Color
  @ViewBuilder private let tooltip: () -> Tooltip
  @Binding private var visible: Bool

  init(alignment: Edge, visible: Binding<Bool>, backgroundColor: Color = .white, @ViewBuilder tooltip: @escaping () -> Tooltip) {
    self.alignment = alignment
    self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    self.tooltip = tooltip

    _visible = visible
  }

  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    TooltipPopup(content: content, alignment: alignment, visible: $visible, backgroundColor: backgroundColor, tooltip: tooltip)
  }

}
```

...and use it like this:

```swift
Text("I'm a text")
  .tooltip(alignment: .top, visible: .constant(true), backgroundColor: .green) {
    Text("I'm a tooltip")
      .frame(width: 100.0)
      .padding(.fullPadding)
  }
```

Since the view the tooltip "tips" typically is just a leaf view often deep inside the view hierarchy, the view modifier is not aware of the presence or size of its parent views. Because of this, tooltip needs to be sized from the outside. In simple cases, providing a width is enough, but in more complicated ones, more information on layout is necessary. For example (again, with a help of `ChildSizeReader`):

```swift
ChildSizeReader(size: $contentSize) {
  VStack {
    FancyScreenCode()
    Button(action: action) {
      Text("What is this?")
    }
      .tooltip(alignment: .top, visible: $visible) {
        FancyTooltipContent()
          .frame(width: contentSize.width - (2.0 * 8.0))
          .fixedSize()
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for this :). Would you know how to make it so the tooltip takes the entire screen width minus 20pts padding on leading and trailing sides without hardcoding the width to a random value? Tried applying the technique of your last code block but cant seem to make it work.

Comment: I use this technique in a real app in production, works as expected to me. Are you sure you use the `ChildSizeReader` as described? I can try to help, but you need to tell me more what exactly doesn't work in your case.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and willingness to help :). So afaik (and correct me if Im wong please) this tooltip works but needs an explicit width to be set on whatever View is inside the tooltip (100pts in your example). I need the tooltip to take the entire screen width minus 20pts on leading and trailing margins regardless of what views are inside it. I tried setting the width with UIScreen just to see the results but the layout extends the bounds of the screen and breaks. See here: https://imgur.com/a/48scHeR . If a bigger discussion is worthy I can make a new post and link it here. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are correct that the width must be set explicitly with this solution. Hence the use of `ChildSizeReader`—you can wrap any view with it, read its size, and use it for settings the width of the tooltip view.

Comment: Yup, I got that. Thats why I tried using UIScreen.main.bounds.width to make the inner Text view take the entire width of the screen (I know getting the screen width with UIScreen is a bad practice, just did it for testing purposes) and it still breaks like on this picture: https://imgur.com/a/tWSHjXM . I can make a post on this and link it here if you feel like seeing the entire code :).

Comment: Oh, now I understand the challenge. Judging from your screenshot, the tooltip is properly sized. The problem is that it's pointing to a view that is not centred, and that is why it's kind of shifted towards one side of the screen. I'm afraid this solution doesn't support asymmetrical tooltips.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). What do you mean exactly with "pointing to a view that is not centered"? centered in relation to what? You mean it only works fine for Views that are in the middle of the screen? And yeah this seems quite a challenge tbh, been stuck on this for quite some time now. Would you have any pointers on how to accomplish this by any chance? To at least know where to start at least. Thanks again for the invaluable help :).

Comment: I mean that the tooltip is centered related to the view it points to: If the tooltip is set to a width wider than the "source" view, there's a chance one of it's edges will be hidden beyound the screen edge. This solution is not suitable for placing the tooltip randomly, the tooltip will always be symmetrical with its source view.

Answer (score 0):

This is from Kodeco https://www.kodeco.com/books/swiftui-cookbook/v1.0/chapters/5-create-a-popover-in-swiftui

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var showPopover = false

  var body: some View {
    Button("Show Popover") {
      showPopover.toggle()
    }
    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    .popover(isPresented: $showPopover,
             attachmentAnchor: .point(.topLeading),
             content: {
      Text("This is a Popover")
        .padding()
        .frame(minWidth: 300, maxHeight: 400)
        .background(.red)
        .presentationCompactAdaptation(.popover)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: This is sweet but requires iOS16.4 as a minimum

Comment: This api is available from ios14 please check once more

Comment: Hmm nope, .presentationCompactAdaptation is 16.4 & up.