# onTapGesture triggered outside the view it modifies

Tags: ios, swiftui

The `onTapGesture` modifier is triggered, when I tap another view.

Here's my view, reduced to a minimal reproducible example:

```swift
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    Menu {
      ForEach(["Option 1", "Option 2"], id: \.self) { item in
        Button(item) {
          currentItem = item
          expanded.toggle()
        }
      }
    } label: {
      HStack {
        Text(currentItem ?? "Pick something…")
          .animation(.default, value: currentItem)
        Spacer()
        Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
          .rotationEffect(expanded ? .degrees(-180.0) : .zero)
          .animation(.default, value: expanded)
      }
    }
      .menuOrder(.fixed)
      .onTapGesture { expanded.toggle() }
    Divider()
  }
}

@State private var currentItem: String?
@State private var expanded = false
```

(In short, there's a menu with a custom label, that animates when the menu is expanded and collapsed. I'm aware that there's also `DisclosureGroup`, but it looks and behaves a bit differently and doesn't fit my app's specs.)

When I tap on the `Menu` itself, everything works as expected:
[image: Menu proper animation]

However, if I tap below the `Menu`, the area of `Divider`, the `Menu` is not triggered (expected,) but its `onTapGesture` unexpectedly is triggered and starts the chevron animation:
[image: Unexpected tap detection]

I tried to move `onTapGesture` inside `Menu`'s `label`, but it's not triggered from there at all:
[image: Not triggering example]

Does anyone know what happens there and how it could be fixed? The only thing I can think of right now is that it's a bug in SwiftUI. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### Why is this happening?

This is because you are testing it on iPhone. iPhone has a touch screen and the **Tap** gesture captures a finger hit test which is larger that the tip of the cursor.

You can hold <kbd>option</kbd> key to reveal the finger hit test and see the overlap.

[image: Demo]

<sub>⚠️ The second one is because you are simulating multi-touch</sub>

If you run the same code in the mac environment, it works as you expected.

If you put another touchable elements near this one, the system will pick the closer one to the finger (if simultaneous touch is not possible)

#### Workaround

You can run the tap on specific locations like:

```
let menuHeight: CGFloat = 32 //  Define a height (or get the height using available methods) 
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Menu {
            ForEach(["Option 1", "Option 2"], id: \.self) { item in
                Button(item) {
                    currentItem = item
                    expanded.toggle()
                }
            }
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text(currentItem ?? "Pick something…")
                    .animation(.default, value: currentItem)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                    .rotationEffect(expanded ? .degrees(-180.0) : .zero)
                    .animation(.default, value: expanded)
            }
            .frame(height: menuHeight) //  Set the height (or just get the height using available methods)
        }
        .menuOrder(.fixed)
        .simultaneousGesture(
            SpatialTapGesture().onEnded { value in //  Use this type of tap gesture
                if (0...menuHeight).contains(value.location.y) { //  Limit the action in the valid range
                    expanded.toggle()
                }
            }
        )

        Divider()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising: Checking location passed to `onTapGesture(coordinateSpace: .local)` works. However, I obviously can't hardcode the values. It wouldn't work, for instance, with dynamic fonts. Do you have any suggestions how to make it work with dynamic height? I.e., what do you mean by "available methods"? :) I tried to play with `GeometryReader`, but first of all it breaks the layout, if I wrap the `Menu` with it; secondly, comparing the view height from `GeometryReader` with the tap location surprisingly doesn't work.

Comment: There are “available method”s :) using the background modifier with the geometryreader or using a PreferenceKey.

Comment: Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77358264/5623035) to fine the size of a selfSize component.

Comment: As a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77436875/7016052) precisely explains the problem and guides to the proper solution, but I want to post my two cents nevertheless. My updated to the answer should provide the exact solution to the problem, when preserving self-sizing is crucial.

So, combining the approach of the accepted answer with the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77358264/5623035) we have this:

```swift
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    Menu {
      ForEach(["Option 1", "Option 2"], id: \.self) { item in
        Button(item) {
          currentItem = item
          expanded.toggle()
        }
      }
    } label: {
      ChildSizeReader(size: $menuSize) {
        HStack {
          Text(currentItem ?? "Pick something…")
            .animation(.default, value: currentItem)
          Spacer()
          Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
            .rotationEffect(expanded ? .degrees(-180.0) : .zero)
            .animation(.default, value: expanded)
        }
          .contentShape(Rectangle())
      }
    }
      .menuOrder(.fixed)
      .onTapGesture(coordinateSpace: .local) { location in
        guard (location.y > .zero) && (location.y < menuSize.height) else {
          return
        }
        expanded.toggle()
      }
    Divider()
  }
}

@State private var currentItem: String?
@State private var expanded = false
@State private var menuSize: CGSize = .zero
```

Which implies you have `ChildSizeReader` defined and implemented as this:

```swift
struct ChildSizeReader<Content: View>: View {

  var body: some View {
    content()
      .background(GeometryReader {
        Color.clear.preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: $0.size)
      })
      .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { size = $0 }
  }

  private let content: () -> Content
  @Binding private var size: CGSize

  init(size: Binding<CGSize>, content: @escaping () -> Content) {
    self.content = content
    _size = size
  }

}

private struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
  static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
  static func reduce(value _: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) { }
}
```

The result:
[image: Tap area detection]

Again, all kudos go to [@mojtaba-hosseini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5623035/mojtaba-hosseini).