# SwiftUI Spotlight / Speech Bubble / Tooltip component over a wrapped UIView

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui, uikit

So basically my View consists of a SwiftUI `ZStack` that holds all of my components. One of this components is a `UIViewRepresentable` wrapper that adapts the UIKit view (that comes from a 3rd party library) to be used within my SwiftUI View. This all works great, however I now need to build an Onboarding experience that consists of a speech bubble and a spotlight (the latter referring to highlighting a specific part of the component while turning down the opacity of the entire background view, so it stands out, something like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TakuSemba/Spotlight/master/arts/logo_yello.png)).

I've been able to create the spech bubble part just fine by following [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77036748/16845586) but am struggling trying to spotlight a specific part of the wrapped UIView (more specifically, a UIStackView subview).

My current code is something like this:

```
//Demo Component List
enum Component {
    case firstComponent
    case secondComponent
    case thirdComponent
}

//Demo ViewModel
class ViewModel {
    let components: [Component] = [.firstComponent, .secondComponent, .thirdComponent]
}

struct SwiftUIComponentsView: View {
    
    let viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()
    @State private var isOverlayEnabled = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< viewModel.components.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    switch viewModel.components[index] {
                    case .firstComponent:
                        // Wrapped UIKit component, theres a specific UIStackView within this UIView that I need to highlight / spotlight.
                        SwiftUIWrappedViewRepresentable()
                        //Speech bubble which works fine
                            .overlay(
                                TooltipView(alignment: .bottom, isVisible: $isOverlayEnabled, content: {
                                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                                        Text("Some onboarding hint that guides the user through the spotlighted component")
                                    }
                                    .frame(width: 300)
                                })
                            )
                            .zIndex(2)
                    case .secondComponent:
                        Text("Second Component")
                    case .thirdComponent:
                        Text("Third Component")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ToolTip View (its the same as the linked SO answer though!):

```
struct TooltipView<Content: View>: View {
    let alignment: Edge
    @Binding var isVisible: Bool
    let content: () -> Content
    let arrowOffset = CGFloat(8)

    private var oppositeAlignment: Alignment {
        let result: Alignment
        switch alignment {
        case .top: result = .bottom
        case .bottom: result = .top
        case .leading: result = .trailing
        case .trailing: result = .leading
        }
        return result
    }

    private var theHint: some View {
        content()
            .padding()
            .background(Color.white)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .background(
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.gray)
                    .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(45))
                    .offset(x: alignment == .leading ? arrowOffset : 0)
                    .offset(x: alignment == .trailing ? -arrowOffset : 0)
                    .offset(y: alignment == .top ? arrowOffset : 0)
                    .offset(y: alignment == .bottom ? -arrowOffset : 0)
                
                , alignment: oppositeAlignment
            )
            .padding()
            .fixedSize()
    }

    var body: some View {
        if isVisible {
            GeometryReader { proxy1 in

                // Use a hidden version of the hint to form the footprint
                theHint
                    .hidden()
                    .overlay(
                        GeometryReader { proxy2 in
                            // The visible version of the hint
                            theHint
                                .drawingGroup()
                                .shadow(radius: 4)
                                // Center the hint over the source view
                                .offset(
                                    x: -(proxy2.size.width / 2) + (proxy1.size.width / 2),
                                    y: -(proxy2.size.height / 2) + (proxy1.size.height / 2)
                                )
                                // Move the hint to the required edge
                                .offset(x: alignment == .leading ? (-proxy2.size.width / 2) - (proxy1.size.width / 2) : 0)
                                .offset(x: alignment == .trailing ? (proxy2.size.width / 2) + (proxy1.size.width / 2) : 0)
                                .offset(y: alignment == .top ? (-proxy2.size.height / 2) - (proxy1.size.height / 2) : 0)
                                .offset(y: alignment == .bottom ? (proxy2.size.height / 2) + (proxy1.size.height / 2) : 0)
                        }
                    )
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                isVisible.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My doubt basically relies on what would the best approach be towards drawing the spotlight rectangle above the wrapped UIView. Should I draw it from the SwiftUI part? If so, how would I know the exact location and size of the inner UIStackView so I can draw it above the UIKit StackView? Should I draw it on the UIKit component directly (comes from a 3rd party library so this may be sorta more complicated)?.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For pure SwiftUI, you would create a spotlight using PreferenceKeys for getting the 'frame' of the view and use a .clipShape modifier for the actual spotlight. That's quite a bit of code, but pretty reusable and clean to use. The difficulty here is getting the frame from a UIView. You could try to explicitly communicate the frame via a binding, use a notification or inspect the view hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks the reply. That would allow me to get the frame of the entire wrapped UIView component, right? But the spotlight needs to be drawn above a UIStackView that is only a tiny part of the entire UIView component. Im pretty lost tbh :O.

Comment: If you can get the frame of the UIStackView in UIKit (via your wrapped UIView) you can communicate that via a binding or a notification. if you do not have direct access to the parent of the UIStackView, you'll have to inspect the UIView hierarchy to find the UIStackView.

Comment: Well the parent of the UIStackView is the entire UIView component itself, I guess I do have access to that as thats what im wrapping with UIViewRepresentable to use in SwiftUI in the first place, right?. However, the child stack view which needs to be spotlighted is a private var on a 3rd party lib so I guess that means I dont have access to it directly? I may be able to turn that var public if that means being able to draw the spotlight from SwiftUI. As to the last two things, would it be too much to ask to show an example of communicating the frame with binding and inspecting the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have access to the parent of the UIStackView, you can get the frame from the stack view and communicate that back to the SwiftUI world.

The `UIViewHierarchy` here is the view containing the stackView of interest. You can override layoutSubviews to keep track of the current frame of the stackView. You can communicate this via a delegate.

```
protocol UIViewHierarchyDelegate: AnyObject {
    func report(frame: CGRect)
}

class UIViewHierarchy: UIView {
    let stackView: UIStackView
    weak var delegate: UIViewHierarchyDelegate?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        stackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 20, height: 20))
        super.init(frame: frame)
        stackView.backgroundColor = .green
        self.addSubview(stackView)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        delegate?.report(frame: stackView.frame)
    }
}
```

In your UIViewRepresentable you can create a Coordinator and set that as the delegate for getting the frame. From the delegate you can set a binding.

```
struct Wrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var frame: CGRect
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIViewHierarchy {
        let view = UIViewHierarchy()
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewHierarchy, context: Context) {
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: UIViewHierarchyDelegate {
        let parent: Wrapper
        
        init(parent: Wrapper) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func report(frame: CGRect) {
            parent.frame = frame
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can use the frame in your SwiftUI Views:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var frame: CGRect = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        Wrapper(frame: $frame)
            .overlay {
                ZStack {
                    Color.clear

                    Rectangle()
                        .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 2)
                        .frame(width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
                        // position is the center of the view
                        .position(x: frame.midX,
                                  y: frame.midY)
                        
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of  the wrapper here  when you can get position of SwiftUI element without the wrapper ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri OP wants to get the position (and dimensions) of a subview of a UIView, not a SwiftUI View.

Comment: Yup! I need to draw a SwiftUI Spotlight view above a subview of a UIView that is already wrapped with a UIViewRepresentable. @JackGoossen this seems great, so the idea is to send the frame of the inner UISTackview from UIKit to SwiftUI via the Coordinator. Once I have the frame, position the overlay using said frame. Sadly I can instantiate the parent view but not modify its implementation, but maybe I can draft a quick PR to the lib owner and get it approved. Will try this later today or early tomorrow and tell you how it goes! Please stick around! Thank you so much this makes perfect sense!

Comment: @stompy If you can instantiate the UIView you can wrap it in another UIView and search the subviews (recursively) for the view of interest. If you can only instantiate the UIViewRepresentable, it is best to ask the lib owner to make the UIView available.

Comment: Hey @JackGoossen ! My apologies for the slight delay in replying, I just wanted to test a bit before going further. I do have some updates but SO doesnt let me write much here, so I made a quick Pastebin to be able to provide some more details. Thanks again :). You can find it here: https://pastebin.com/e76gn1GW