# Spotlighting / Highlighting a specific part of a UIView that is wrapped with a UIViewRepresentable?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, uiviewrepresentable

For extra context, this is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77537312/swiftui-spotlight-speech-bubble-tooltip-component-over-a-wrapped-uiview/). Would appreciate reading that post as theres quite a bunch of context as to my initial approach and what I need to ultimately accomplish.

I basically have an entire UIView which is being wrapped to be able to be used with SwiftUI with a `UIViewRepresentable`. This UIView displays some shimmering effects while `isLoading = true` and removes these loading views and renders a bunch of `UIStackView` subviews once `isLoading = false`. As said on the linked post (on my last reply to the user that provided code examples), I need to be able to get the frame of a specific `UIStackView` (so as to draw a spotlight rectangle above it) but only when the `UIView` is done loading and the `UIStackView` has already been rendered on screen. Something such as `layoutSubViews` but from the SwiftUI part of things.

This needs to be accomplished without:

- Having access / modifying the UIView in question since it comes from a 3rd party lib.
- Subclassing the UIView as the class is marked as `final`.

In order to get the UIStackView frame, my approach was to inspect the superview of a button I set on the UIRepresentable (this superview is exactly the stackView I need), so my representable would look something like this:

```
struct DemoUIViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var frame: CGRect // binding used to communicate the frame to the View
    @Binding var model: model //all needed properties to set the UIView
    var isLoading: Bool //isLoading property that tracks the loading state
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> DemoView {
        let view = DemoView()
        view.isLoading = true
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: DemoView, context: Context) {
        uiView.buttons = model.buttons
        uiView.isLoading = isLoading
        if !isLoading {
            guard let frame = model.buttons.first?.superview?.frame else { return }
            self.frame = frame //updates the binding property so the view update progagates to the @State property on the View
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly, this doesnt work as the frame is grabbed before the shimmering views are actually removed and the UIStackViews are rendered on screen, so I get a bogus frame.
If I do something like:

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: DemoView, context: Context) {
    uiView.buttons = model.buttons
    uiView.isLoading = isLoading
    if !isLoading {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
            guard let frame = balanceModel.bottomActionButtons.first?.superview?.frame else { return }
            self.frame = frame
        }
    }
}
```

This works great as it gives time for the UIView to update and lay out its subviews (remove shimmer views and render the UIStackViews). But, this is super hacky and not a good practice at all.

Any other tips you may imagine to accomplish this to be able to hightlight/spotlight a specific part of a UIView that is wrapped with a UIViewRepresentable? Is my initial approach of grabbing the frame somewhat correct? Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you wrap the `DemoView` in a custom UIView subclass, and override the `layoutSubviews` method? That would give you a hook into the layout engine. You might be able to check `isLoading` there and take the appropriate measurements when it is false

Comment: You mean subclassing the UIView and overriding the layoutSubviews method? Or adding the UIView as a subview of another custom UIView? If you mean the former, as I said in the post, I cannot subclass the UIView as it is marked as final and comes from a 3rd party library.

Comment: @Rengers meant the latter (adding DemoView as a subview), which is exactly what I recommended in the pastebin you linked in the other question.

Comment: @JackGoossen OMG! I literally wasn't even aware Pastebin allowed replies so I never even checked Pastebin again, I was expecting a reply but on the actual SO thread/post and since I never got any, I just made this new thread, my bad. Just checked and noticed you replied with not only one but two approaches. Thank you so much!  So it seems adding the 3rd party UIView as a subview of a custom UIView allows me to override layoutSubviews and that gets called everytime the inner layoutSubViews (from the 3rd party UIView) method is called? I will try this tomorrow and update here on how it goes! :)

Comment: @JackGoossen Just wanted to say adding it as a subview and overriding layoutSubviews indeed worked like a charm. Thank you so much! I will continue with the spotlighting tomorrow and update on how it goes!

Comment: Hi ! Made a new chapter for this saga, if anyone likes to take a look id appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: oops forgot to add the link! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77687680/swiftui-reusable-guided-tour-spotlight-effect-view-component