# Make SwiftUI Shape take entire screen width minus padding while using position modifier

Tags: ios, swiftui, layout

I need to position a view based on a given `CGRect` frame and a few pixels below render a `RoundedRectangle` that always takes the entire width of the screen minus 20pts horizontal padding (regardless of the inner Text length). To position the first View I am using the `position` modifier which seems to work just fine, but when it comes to drawing the second `RoundedRectangle` and make it always take the entire width minus 20 pts horizontal padding its not working as for whatever reason the View is positioned all the way to the left and paddings ignored (check the outcome picture).

Code is simple and the following:

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    let testFrame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 200, width: 240, height: 48)
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                    .stroke(.purple, lineWidth: 4)
                    .frame(width: testFrame.width, height: testFrame.height)
                //This should always take the entire width of the screen minus 20 pts horizontal padding and height be dynamic depending on inner Text / View sizes and lengths.
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Some title")
                    Text("Some subtitle")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding()
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).foregroundColor(.red))
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            }
            .position(x: testFrame.midX, y: testFrame.midY)
    }
}
```

Outcome:

[image]

Comment: This is a rather odd thing to do in SwiftUI - it is rare that you would need to do layout explicitly with `CGRect`s. This might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Can you explain more about the context? What is the purpose of putting the rounded rectangle in a specific frame?

Comment: I agree doing layout with CGRects sounds odd but I cant really think of other way of doing it while supporting UIKit UIViews and SwiftUI Views.
Context as to what I need to accomplish is on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77687680/swiftui-reusable-guided-tour-spotlight-effect-view-component. I need to be able to draw the spotlight effect around ANY view (be it a UIKit UIView or a normal SwiftUI view). The code on this post doesnt include the complex tooltip modifier for brevity purposes, but the concept should be the same (two rounded rectangles one after the other). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue there, I think, is that you are trying to align the red caption "bubble" with both the purple highlight and the container. Regularly, instead of wrangling with "built-in" layouts, I would approach it with either the `GeometryReader` or a custom `Layout` just for mental clarity but here's both ways:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct E25: View {
    
    let testFrame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 200, width: 240, height: 48)
    
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
            .stroke(.purple, lineWidth: 4)
            .frame(width: testFrame.width, height: testFrame.height)
            .position(x: testFrame.midX, y: testFrame.midY)
            .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Some title")
                    Text("Some subtitle")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding()
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).foregroundColor(.red))
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                .offset(y: testFrame.maxY + 20)
            }
    }
    
    var altBody: some View {
        CustomLayout(rect: testFrame) {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                .stroke(.purple, lineWidth: 4)
            
            ZStack {
                Color.red
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Some title")
                    Text("Some subtitle")
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }
    }
    
    struct CustomLayout: Layout {
        let rect: CGRect
        var captionGap: CGFloat = 20
        
        func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
            
            // The highligh view
            guard let highlight = subviews.first else { return }
            highlight.place(
                at: CGPoint(
                    x: bounds.minX + rect.minX,
                    y: bounds.minY + rect.minY
                ),
                anchor: .topLeading,
                proposal: ProposedViewSize(rect.size)
            )
            
            // The optional caption view
            guard subviews.count >= 2 else { return }
            let caption = subviews[1]
            
            caption.place(
                at: CGPoint(
                    x: bounds.minX,
                    y: bounds.minY + rect.maxY + captionGap
                ),
                anchor: .topLeading,
                proposal: ProposedViewSize(width: bounds.width, height: .none)
            )
        }
        
        func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
            proposal.replacingUnspecifiedDimensions()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    E25()
}
```

The first approach is a slight modification of your code but with an `overlay`. Somewhat counter-intuitively, it works because `position` make the modified view "greedy" (e.g. the view now takes all available space).

The second approach, (the `altBody`) doesn't save any code, but, in my opinion, is somewhat easier to understand and reuse.

Let me know is this resolves the issue or if you have further questions.

Regards,
–Baglan

Comment: In the second approach, `CustomLayout` assumes two subviews, however, it might be even cleaner to have two separate layouts, one for the highlight and one for the caption bubble.

Comment: Yeey this is great, thank you so much! Sadly I gotta support iOS 15 so I cant use the Layout protocol yet, but I tried the first approach and it seems to be working fine. Ill keep experimenting and reply again to this thread should I have further questions (not sure wether you'll get notified though). Thanks again!

Comment: Would you know how to make it so I can alternate between showing the second RoundedRectangle above the first RoundedRectangle + 20pts padding (instead of below like what I asked initially)? I tried offseting the second RoundedRect using minY instead of maxY but it seems it aint working. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello again! I suspected that would be your next question :) Essentially, when positioning the bubble below the are of interest, you align the bubble to the top and shift it down. Otherwise, you align the bubble to the bottom and shift it up. To calculate the offset from the bottom you need to know the viewport height and the most straightforward way to do it is to use the `GeometryReader`. Here's the “refactored” code: https://gist.github.com/Baglan/38560bf95df04410d8a844d1027474b4

Comment: Omg thank you so so much Baglan, this is exactly what I was looking for. I need to work on my GeometryReader skills tbh. Seems like the only missing part I need to finish my SpeechBubble component is to position a small Triangle (with rounded tip, but I can check how to do that later) with its tip pointing to the exact center of the first RoundedRectangle (supporting either when the bubble is on top or on bottom). Any clue? I will start messing with overlays and backgrounds to see if I get any positive results, but any pointers are greatly appreciated as well. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: The most pragmatic way I can think of would be, as you mentioned, to add a triangle in the right place. As a bit of a challenge for myself, I would, probably, draw a `Path` instead and use it as a `.background()` for the bubble. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: Hi Baglan! Ive been reading on Path and think I got the bare minimum to start experimenting haha. So basically I need the tip of the Triangle to point to the exact center of the view to highlight. I came up with this shape (https://pastebin.com/xMQGP862) which uses the given frame midX position to draw the first line up until the start of the Triangle, draws the triangle and then just completes the rectangle, but for whatever reason it does not point to the center of the first RoundedRectangle. Any tip? Id prefer using Paths but either a custom Shape or roundedrect+triangle works tbh. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @stompy, the custom shape thing is just for fun really, a small bit that you can hone your programming chops on, I'm all for pragmatic solutions otherwise :). As it happens, I just had to implement something very similar and it's very easy to combine paths with `.union()` and there is a ready-made `Path` constructor for rounded rectangles. As for alignment, you've drawn the tip 10 points to the right of the intended location (the tip should be in the middle, not the left point of the base) and you didn't account for the padding. Otherwise spot on!

Comment: Hi Baglan! Thanks again, seriously. So I continued my adventures regarding this and I did have some progress (was able to draw the pointer to the middle for the case where the bubble is located below the view), but failed when it needed to be positioned above the View. I cant use .union as I gotta support iOS 15, sadly. For clarity, I went ahead and made a new post with the remaining questions I have, would love if you could stop by! Its here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77941988/drawing-a-swiftui-speech-bubble-shape-with-rounded-tip-based-on-screen-positioni . Again, thank you!

Comment: From the other question I see that you've gone the "brute force" route and have drawn the whole shape – I would have done that too in the past, too lazy for it now :) so, back to the triangle idea: https://gist.github.com/Baglan/2d831f5f5ec883123660d6f1a417668c is this, roughly, what you had in mind? In general, I would recommend "parametrizing" components in this kind of situations – forces you to consider problems in more formalized and generic ways.

Comment: Hello again Baglan and thank you so much once again :). Ive been experimenting with this and I came up with a solution that doesn't position the pointer on the Shape itself but instead just uses a second overlay and uses the position modifier to position it correctly while rotating the pointer 180 degreess should it point down and not up. You can check it here: https://pastebin.com/pP8NMYCd .
I went ahead and posted what I believe are the two last issues Im having at the end of that pastebin should you dare to keep spending your valuable time giving me a hand. Again, thank you so so much.

Comment: These two problems are weirdly connected :) If you can use iOS16, there is a `UnevenRoundedRectangle` which allows you to specify corner radii (fancy latin for radiuses :)) for each of the corners. Essentially, you can calculate the radius of the corner where the pointer is based on how close it is to the corner.

Comment: As for the rounded tip, instead of drawing a `Path` (which you should, probably do), you can draw a `UnevenRoundedRectangle`, rotate it 45 degrees and, maybe scale it horizontally to achieve a slightly different shape. Let me know if you need a code sample. And good luck – quite a deep feature, it turns out :)

Comment: Target is iOS 15 as of now so I cant use UnevenRoundedRectangle, sadly. For making the tip rounded I guess all I need is a custom shape that places an arc at the tip and thats all, Im currently using a normal triangle and it works fine, but the tip aint rounded. For the "bug", I guess I would need to compare the midX point of the CGRect and somehow figure out wether it resembles a point that is near to the edges and if so, position it just before the cornerRadius of the bubble starts, something like a "maximum offset". Current code is this: https://pastebin.com/EVE42uSk . Thanks again, really.

Comment: And yeah, truly a deep feature for someone who never messed with custom shapes nor custom View placements nor manual frame calculations haha. While a bit stressful (not gonna lie hehe), I am learning quite a bit in the process. Wouldn't have gotten so far without your help tbh though, so huge thanks. If you figure how to tackle these two last (hopefully) challenges, a code sample would be great, yeah, though I don't want to abuse of your kindness, really. Either way I will keep messing with arcs and shapes hoping I get somewhere near the desired result :).

Comment: I think, the initial design is not well suited to serve all these edge cases. At this stage I would reconsider my design instead of going into all that complexity. Perhaps something like this: https://gist.github.com/Baglan/b100ad46551ee9e81c3b39aa4524771e with a curved line pointer?